# How to make a git repository past of a new one

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I have a two repositories `A` and `B`, `repo A` is my app which I made last year and `repo B` is the new version of it, I put them into 2 repositories but now I want to make `repo A` as the past commits happened in `repo B`, like adding a to b and nothing happen like that a happened before and now b is the new files

Answer (score 1):

From `B` you can [rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) `B` onto `A`, and then overwrite `B` with the result.

Here's one way to achieve that:

*Note: `git push --force` is destructive, meaning you are overwriting history. You may want to push to a feature branch first, to test it out.*

```
$ cd B
$ git checkout master
$ git pull
$ git pull -r <URL_TO_A> master
$ git push --force
```

Note that this assumes `master` to be the naming of the main branch on both repo's - this may have a different name (e.g. `main`).

---

You may find this helpful to get more context: [Merging vs. Rebasing (Atlassian Git Tutorial)](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing)